# Add Multiple Workspace Cleanup for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Can I have multiple *Delete workspace when build is done* executions in a single job?

- failure status: clear all workspace
- success status: clear only distribution package directories (**/target/dist)

We break our builds into compilation and test jobs with build-stalker plugin providing the link between the two.  Compilation job doesn't clean up after itself as test job will do so but we don't run a test job for each compilation job (only the latest in a 4 hour period) leaving orphaned workspaces.

I'd like a way to have the orphaned workspaces have less impact and a selective status based cleanup is one way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a Jenkins plugin that supplies such a feature.

I'd establish the following:

- Let each compile build write a line with its workspace path, e.g.:

  `.../jenkins/workspace/<...compile job...>/`

  by using a script in a language of your choice (bash, Groovy, cmd, ...) to a file like:

  `.../jenkins/workspace/toBeWipedOut`
- Create a job that runs a script in a language of your choice periodically that:

  - reads the file
  - deletes the workspaces mentioned therein except the last
  - removes all lines therein except the last

or

- Let each compile build write a line with its job name.
- See [Wipe out workspaces of all jobs](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Wipe+out+workspaces+of+all+jobs) for how to wipe out workspaces by job name.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. I'll use groovy since it makes cross platform a snap.